# Angular 5 + HttpClient doesn't send Headers on GET

Tags: angular, angular5

I'm using Angular 5 [https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get[1]](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get) to do an HTTP GET request, which needs Authorization header.

Can someone point the issue in this code? Thanks.

```
this.http.get<Company[]>('http://localhost:8080/api/company/list',
      {
        headers:
          {'Authorization': 'Bearer 56155553-87f8-47f3-be87-8a4acf4ccacf'}
      })
      .subscribe(companies => {
        this.companies = companies;
        // Calling the DT trigger to manually render the table
        this.dtTrigger.next();
      });
```

I'm getting the following error, which I suspect headers are not passing correctly.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/api/company/list. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401
```

FYI: There is no problem with the Bearer token as well as CORS configurations.

In the server side, I have used Spring Boot. Following is the CORS configuration which I have added.

```
@Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeader("Origin"));
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, Authorization, X-Custom-Header");

        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
```

Comment: The preflight request is using the http method "OPTIONS" which needs to not be protected by authorization. Or else your "GET" request will fail.

Comment: @transporter_room_3 How can I make it work ? Please help me out.

Comment: *I'm getting the following error, which I suspect headers are not passing correctly.* Why would you "suspect" that if you can check that in browser? Either headers are sent or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser is making an OPTIONS request to ask permission to make the request with custom HTTP headers (i.e. the Authorization header).

The server is responding with a `401` (not authorized) error.

You need to exclude the OPTIONS request from the requirement to be authorized.